# AsyncStorage behaviour

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, react-native, expo

I bumped into a weird behaviour of `AsyncStorage` that I couldn't wrap my head around and would appreciate anyone who can explain to me what's happening behind the scene (i.e. fail cases and why)

Here's a code I'm working on:

```
componentDidMount() {
        let _this = this;

        AsyncStorage.getItem('token', (err, data) => {
            setTimeout(() => {
                if(data !== null){
                    this.setState({isReady: true, isLoggedIn: true});
                    store.dispatch({type: t.LOGGED_IN, token: data});
                }
                else{
                    this.setState({isReady: true, isLoggedIn: false})
                    store.dispatch({type: t.LOGGED_OUT});
                }
            }, 3000)
            console.log(err);
        });
    }
```

As you can see, I'm passing a `callback` function to `getItem()` as per the documentation, which basically tells me if the user has logged in before and hasn't logged out since(i.e. the token still persists in the device/app somewhere).
This code succeeded the first time, retrieving the old token I stored via reducer:

```
export default function authReducer(state = initialState, action)
{
    switch (action.type) {
        case t.LOGGED_IN:{
            AsyncStorage.setItem('token', action.token);
            return Object.assign({}, state, { isLoggedIn: true, token: action.token });
        }
        case t.LOGGED_OUT:{
            AsyncStorage.removeItem('token');
            return Object.assign({}, state, {isLoggedIn: false, token: null});
        }
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

However, on the second time I reloaded the app, the `AsyncStorage` will always fail to retrieve the data even after I tried logging in again and again.

I tried variations of `AsyncStorage` calls as well, i.e. using `await`, `.then` plus `.catch`, but they all lead to the same result.

My questions are:

1. On fail cases, I was under the impression that `getItem()` will still call the callback function I passed since there's an `error` on the param list. However, my console.log was never run in the above case. Am I expecting something I shouldn't be here?
2. Why would it only keep failing from second time around? Is there a case where calling `setItem()` on the same key more than once without ever deleting it will cause the storage to fail? (I know for sure that the first try was a success because I printed the retrieved token from async storage)
3. Does this have anything to do with the fact that I'm loading my app from Expo and initialized the app with CRNA? will this somehow make the asyncStorage persistence quality different?

thanks in advance! :)

EDIT: Upon further inspection, it seems stopping the packager and running it again seems to allow the app to once again succeed in retrieving the old token, but if I refresh the app again, after editing the code, `getItem()` will fail again.  Is this a thing with Expo and persistent storage then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reducers must be free from **side-effects**, since it is a pure function.

As mentioned in the [docs](https://redux.js.org/glossary#reducer)

> They must be **pure functions**—*functions that return the exact same output for given inputs*. They should also be **free** of side-effects.

*Side Effects - when a procedure changes a variable from outside its scope*

A better approach would be to use [redux-saga](https://github.com/redux-saga/redux-saga), *that is like a separate thread for your side effects model*.

Comment: Ah I see, must've missed that one! Thanks heaps! :)

Answer (score 0):

So the problem is fixed now, thanks to a more experienced programmer friend of mine. 
Turns out my mistake is that I put the `AsyncStorage.setItem()` call in reducer, which he said is `deterministic` in nature.
I moved the call to the `actions.js` of that class right before dispatch, and it works!

So instead of

```
export default function authReducer(state = initialState, action)
{
    switch (action.type) {
        case t.LOGGED_IN:{
            AsyncStorage.setItem('token', action.token);
            return Object.assign({}, state, { isLoggedIn: true, token: action.token });
        }
        case t.LOGGED_OUT:{
            AsyncStorage.removeItem('token');
            return Object.assign({}, state, {isLoggedIn: false, token: null});
        }
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

I did

```
export default function authReducer(state = initialState, action)
{
    switch (action.type) {
        case t.LOGGED_IN:{
            return Object.assign({}, state, { isLoggedIn: true, token: action.token });
        }
        case t.LOGGED_OUT:{
            return Object.assign({}, state, {isLoggedIn: false, token: null});
        }
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

Plus this

```
export function login(data, successCB, errorCB) {
    return (dispatch) => {
        api.login(data, function (success, data, error) {
            if (success && data.exists) {
                AsyncStorage.setItem('token', data.token); //NOTE THIS
                dispatch({type: t.LOGGED_IN, token: data.token});
                successCB(data);
            }else if (error) errorCB(error)
        });
    };
}

export function signOut(successCB, errorCB){
  return (dispatch) => {
    AsyncStorage.removeItem('token'); //NOTE THIS
    dispatch({type: t.LOGGED_OUT});
    successCB();
  }
}
```

But my question still `persists` (pardon the pun), "Why does that simple modification works? did I understand the mechanism of `reducers` and `dispatchers` wrong here?"

Also, what does being `deterministic` means and have to do with incompatibilities with `Async` calls?

If anyone can explain the concept to me that would be awesome! :D